# Unity WebGL WebcamTexture webcam light stays on after disabling camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, webcam, unity-webgl

I'm using the following script to enable/disable the webcam on WebGL.

It works fine on the Editor but on the browser, the webcam light stays on after disabling the WebcamTexture.

It happens on Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
WebCamTexture _webcamTexture;

public void Enable()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
    Debug.Log("Enable");
    #endif

    _enabled = true;
}

public void Disable()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
    Debug.Log("Disable");
    #endif

    _enabled = false;
}

#region MONOBEHAVIOUR

void Update()
{
    if(_enabled)
    {
        if(_webcamTexture == null)
        {
            while(!Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam).isDone)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam)) 
            {
                #if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
                Debug.Log("Webcam authorized");
                #endif

                _webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture (WebCamTexture.devices[0].name);
                _webcamTexture.Play (); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                #if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
                Debug.Log("Webcam NOT authorized");
                #endif
            }   
        }
        else if (_webcamTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            if(!_ready)
            {
                if (_webcamTexture.width < 100)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _ready = true;
            }

            if(_webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame)
            {
                _aspectRatioFitter.aspectRatio =  (float)_webcamTexture.width / (float)_webcamTexture.height;

                _imageRectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, -_webcamTexture.videoRotationAngle);

                _image.texture = _webcamTexture;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(_webcamTexture != null) 
        {
            _webcamTexture.Stop ();
            _webcamTexture = null;

            _image.texture = null;
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that code is working in the Editor is because the Editor is made to clean some things up for you. Once you click stop, the camera is automatically stopped even without `WebCamTexture.Stop ();` being called.

Unfortunately, this does not happen in a build. You have to explicitly call `WebCamTexture.Stop ();` to stop it. The right place to do this is in the `Disable()` function.

```
public void Disable()
{
    if(_webcamTexture != null) 
    {
        _webcamTexture.Stop ();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Instead of using a boolean variable to disable the camera, make a function and connect that function to your stop button. When that function is called, it stops the camera.

```
public void disableCamera()
{
    if(_webcamTexture != null) 
    {
        _webcamTexture.Stop ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm calling _webcamTexture.Stop (); inside the Update when _enabled is set to false. I've already tried it inside the Disable method. It should not make any difference, right?

Comment: I know you are. That's simply wrong. The `Update` function is terminated when app exists. What if that if statement is not even running? That's why you should stop/end stuff in the `OnDisable` function and not in the `Update` function. Give my solution a try. This problem happens when you close the tab?

Comment: The Disable method is called when I press a UI button. I'm not terminating the app. I want to enable/disable the camera with the app running. When I close the tab the light turns off.

Comment: Oops. I see what the problem is now. Got it wrong the first time. Why not put `_webcamTexture.Stop ();` in a public function then hook that function up to a button. When you press it, the function calls `_webcamTexture.Stop ();`. That's better than what you have now.

Comment: Yeah, before I had it inside the Disable function (which is called by the UI button) but it's the same. I will move it back into the function, this was me experimenting. But thanks

Comment: No, its the same. The webcam light stays on.

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: Just upgraded to 5.6. But I also had this problem with the 5.5.3

Comment: Check back in few minutes. I will check if I can replicate the problem

Comment: I have an example project if you want to try it. How can I send it to you?

Comment: If you need to send me example project, you must do that with anything lower than 5.6. Unity 5.5 is better. You can upload it to Google Drive and provide the link here.

Comment: Ok, I'm installing the 5.5.3 and I will create the project there. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Here is the project, it already has a webgl build https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rotehbtqyv3fe8/webgl-webcam-Unity5.5.3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hold really quick. Mine is building. I will test yours too after that. It takes so long to build.

Comment: I did a test. What you see is a bug. I will file for a bug report with Unity.

Comment: OK cool. Do you mind sharing here the bug link afterwards. Thanks once again.